# Jquery dynamic TextBoxes with Request.form Iteration

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i am Adding multiple TextBoxes with Jquery in my Application, then in code behind file i want can access the values by Request.form[name]. I want o iterate these textboxes and read values of whatever Text is entered by the user, so i can store it in database.
any idea how can i save the value of these textboxes in Database,
i am working in asp.net 2.0

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var counter = 2;

  $("#addButton").click(function () {

   if (counter > 10) {
     alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
     return false;
   }

   var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);


   newTextBoxDiv.html('<table><tr><td><input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
                          '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" ></td><td><input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
                          '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" ></td><td><input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
                          '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" ></td></tr></table>');

   newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
   return false;


   counter++;
  });
 });
```

Comment: Does your counter increment.. coz your script is always returning false before reaching 'counter++' plus all the three textboxes that you are creating in single statement get the same id.

Comment: hi return false is no issue i can put it after the counter increment and i can change the id's of the text boxes,, but how can i get all these textboxes via request.form in C# and get the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys) 
        {
            if (key.StartsWith("textbox")) 
            {
                string value = Request.Form[key];
                //Do some stuff...
            }
        }
```